# Swift - Optional Void

Tags: swift, option-type

I was busy using `NSURLProtocolClient`'s URLProtocol function:

```
welf?.client?.URLProtocol(welf!, didReceiveResponse: operation.response, cacheStoragePolicy: NSURLCacheStoragePolicy.NotAllowed)
```

I was expecting it to return `Void`. But to my surprise it returns `Void?`

Why is it necessary to make a distinction between `Void` and `Void?`

I have read that `Void` is a type alias for the empty tuple type. So, does this have something to do with a distinction between the empty tuple type vs nil?

Comment: As drewag says. Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSURLProtocolClient_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLProtocolClient/URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:) confirms the return type (there is no mention of an optional return value).

Comment: I was also surprised. In my case I was passing a closure like `{  some?.call() }` and Swift complained since the receiving parameter was expecting a function of type `() -> ()` but that closure had an implicit type of `() -> ()?`. I finally casted the closure to `() -> ()` but I don't know if this is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply because you are using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_368). The method returns `Void`, but it is possible for the whole chain to return `nil` before the method is ever called.

Essentially, a return value of `Void` will mean the call was actually made (self and client both have values) while a `nil` result will mean that one of those were `nil`.

Comment: This is actually a very nice tip! Thanks. Where did you learn about this?

Answer (score 6):

Note that, `()` and `nil` is different:

```
let a:Void? = ()
let b:Void? = nil

a == nil // -> false
b == nil // -> true
```

Using this, you can judge the method has really been invoked or not.

```
let result = welf?.client?.URLProtocol(welf!, didReceiveResponse: operation.response, cacheStoragePolicy: NSURLCacheStoragePolicy.NotAllowed)
if result != nil {
    // success
}
else {
    // `welf?.client` was `nil`
}
```