# unknown function return type in Swift. ()?

Tags: swift

In function types, you can write

```
()->()?
```

And it builds fine! What is the  `()?`?

Comment: I know but what is ()? ? is it optional void?

Comment: Yes. ()? means optional void

Comment: Please show a bit more code with a complete example of how this `()?` is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`() -> ()?` defines a higher order type, taking the *empty tuple* `()` as argument, and returning an `Optional` of the empty tuple, `Optional<()>` or, using the `?` sugar for `Optional`, simply `()?`.

There is a typedef for the empty tuple named `Void`, so all the following are equivalent higher order types:

```
() -> ()?
() -> Optional<()>
() -> Void?
() -> Optional<Void>
```

Example when applied to closures:

```
// c1 through c4 all have the same type, but use
// typedefs (Void) or optional sugar (?) for variations.
var c1: () -> ()? = { return nil }
let c2: () -> Optional<()> = c1
let c3: () -> Void? = c1
let c4: () -> Optional<Void>? = c1
```

Note though that `()` is also *an instance* of the empty tuple (in addition to being use as the *type* for it), meaning we could re-assign e.g. the mutable closure `c1` above to return the *value* `()`:

```
c1 = { return () }
c1 = { return .some(()) }
```

On the other had, as `Void` is simply a typedef for the empty tuple *type*, we'd need to explicitly instantiate a non-optional (named) `Void` instance if we'd like to return "an empty tuple instance" without actually using the `()` value (and only using the `Void` typedef):

```
c1 = {
    let v: Void
    return v
}
```

Generally declaring an non-optional immutable property without assigning a *value* to it is an error in Swift, but since the `Void` typedef, namely the empty tuple, can only hold a single value (`()`), the Swift compiler is seemingly smart enough to allow omitting assigning this only possible value to `v` above (or, a special case for the quite special empty tuple type).

Finally, note that all non-optional `()`-returning closures or functions can omit the return value, and, in function declarations, omit also the type:

```
// Now studying the case of non-optional () return
var c6: () -> () = { print("Implicit () return") }
func f1() { print("Implicit return type, implicit () return") }
func f2() { print("Implicit return type, explicit () return"); return () }
func f3() -> () { print("Explicit return type, implicit () return") }
func f4() -> () { print("Explicit return type, explicit () return"); return () }
c6 = f1
c6 = f2
c6 = f3
c6 = f4
let emptyTupleInstance = c6() // "()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
()?
```

means optional void. I used to write it as (Void)?

Don't think optional and void are the same thing. They are absolutely not. Essentially: ‘void’ is a type, while null is a [special] value.

This should be helpful in explaining it.
[Swift - Optional Void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837951/swift-optional-void)

Comment: And what does it mean to have a function that returns an "optional void"? It really makes no sense.

Comment: It's not _"used to be written"_, `Void` is still just a typealias for the empty tuple, so `()` and `Void` are equivalent.

Comment: I knew I'd get a comment. I only mean by "used to be written" that that's how I wrote it in earlier versions of swift.  Everyone's mileage varies.

Comment: () and void are different. When you check for nil they have different results, so optional void is valid.